# Is there a way to practice Snooker cue action at home?

Tags: training, snooker

I'm wondering what kind of snooker practice can be done at home alone! Cause I have a cue & I just trying to get a nice stance & grip & I don't how can I improve cue action at home with having table!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

Take a video of yours while playing and watch to video to check:

- How is your *stance*. Pause the video at required places and validate if you are really correct and in right balance.
- How is your bridge arm.
- How's is your **striking elbow**. This is very critical when comes to observing the cue action. You should be perpendicular to the ground as much as possible with no action other than the elbow(check shoulder and rest of the arm doesn't move)
- **Head**  : Head or any part of the body should not move while taking the shot on .Most times I was making a mistake of shaking my head when I had to strike hard . Please avoid this.

With above-mentioned, you should be able to improve the cue action with a good flow. Getting the right groove is the key :-)